# c# inheritance in lists

Tags: c#, xml, list, inheritance

I'm trying to build an XML interpreter at the minute and there is a lot of inheritance going on.When I have a list and I want to access the specific type of the abstract is there a short way of doing it? This is what I'm currently doing:

```
abstract class Foo{}
class iFoo : Foo
{
   int bar;
}
class xFoo : Foo
{
   string bar;
}

class Main
{
 List<Foo> fooList;
     public static void Main (string[]args)
     {
         iFoo iBar = fooList[0] as IFoo;
         xFoo xBar = fooList[1] as XFoo;
         iBar.bar = 10;
         xBar.bar = "hello world";
     }
}
```

`*fooList` is initialised and populated in other parts of the code, this is just an example of my problem.

I'm looking for an easier way of doing it, something like this:

```
fooList[0](as type iFoo).bar = 10;
```

Comment: There is no type `iBar`. Do you mean `(fooList[0] as IFoo).bar = 10;`?

Comment: Anything you do that accesses child properties is not going to be type safe  unless you have code that verifies the underlying type.  What if `fooList[0]` is an `XFoo` instead of an `IFoo`?  Perhaps you should look at a different structure than a list of `Foo`s if you know the structure ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword like this:

```
(fooList[0] as IFoo).bar = 10;
```

And

```
(fooList[1] as XFoo).bar = "hello world";
```

Comment: Really should check for `null` when using `as` to guard against null reference exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which Properties or Methods you have on the instance, you can cast to `dynamic` so that the compiler doesnt interfere with it.

It would look like this:

```
dynamic instance = fooList[0];
instance.bar = value;
```

`value` is a placeholder for the value you want to assign.
But keep in mind that the **operation** has to be **valid**. You cannot assign a `string` to an `int` just because you cast to `dynamic`.